# Exited from the main page of Ubuntu

Tags: python, delete, tty

I tried to delete python with `sudo apt purge -y python 3-minimal` and this happened.

[image]

Comment: 1. Your image doesn't seem to be related at all.  2. Don't purge python from Ubuntu, you will be really sorry quite quickly. For one thing `apt` and `apt-get` are heavily dependent on Python.

Comment: whene i use that code this happened and i stuck here

Comment: You have destroyed your system. Reinstall and reload your backups.

Comment: yes i know, can you help me in "Reinstall and reload your backups.' please?